# Adjust position of anchor destinations using Jquery to take into account sticky header

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to adjust the position of the scroll when using anchors because I am using a sticky header and the anchor position seems to base itself off the top even though I have css padding on the main div which works on the pages themselves but when I click an anchor it doesn't work properly.

I put in this smooth scroll code which works fine as long as the anchor links are coming from the page itself but it doesn't have any effect when I navigate directly to the anchor from another page

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 120)
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me get this working so it is the same whether the click comes from another page or within the page that the anchors are on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using CSS I found in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205376/scroll-to-anchor-adjust-for-fixed-menu-at-top).

```
a[name] {
    position: relative;
    top: -160px;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
}
```